# Query Optimization: Looping and Updating multiple rows based on a SELECT in one SQL statement

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    account_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
)

CREATE TABLE transaction (
    transaction_value integer,
    business_period_id FOREIGN_KEY,
    account_id FOREIGN KEY  
)

CREATE TABLE business_period (
    business_period_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE account_balance (
    account_id FOREIGN KEY,
    account_balance integer 
)
```

A business period gets created along with transactions in that business period. I need a way to update the account_balance based on the transactions that happened within the period.

I am currently doing this

```
BEGIN
SELECT account_id, SUM(transaction_value) AS net_impact 
FROM transactions 
WHERE business_period_id=$1 
GROUP BY account_id;
-- at this point this query returns to the client side
```

Let's say this returns an array called `account_impacts`, which is:

```
var account_impacts = [[account_id, net_impact], [account_id, net_impact], [account_id, net_impact], ...]
```

Do individual update statements on the client side (pseudo code):

```
for (var account_impact in account_impacts) {
    var $account_id = account_impact[0]
    var $net_impact = account_impact[1]

    // Execute the follow SQL query
    UPDATE account_balance 
    SET account_balance = account_balance + $net_impact
    WHERE account_id = $account_id
}
COMMIT
```

This query is slow and it is starting to affect performance. 
I am looping on the client side and then executing the update queries individually. Is there a way to execute all of this as a single query in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single query:

```
UPDATE  account_balance ab
SET     account_balance = account_balance + t.transaction_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        account_id
    ,   sum ( transaction_value ) as transaction_value
    FROM    transaction t
    WHERE   business_period_id = 1
    GROUP BY account_id
) t
WHERE   ab.account_id = t.account_id;
```

Comment: Should this be `SET account_balance = account_balance + t.transaction_value`

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea, I added the qualifier 't' for clarity.